# How to convert the extension of the images in dataframe to UPPERCASE

Tags: python, pandas

I have the link of the images in my pandas dataframe in the profile column now i only want to convert the extension of the images into UPPERCASE in pandas

I have tried this but the problem is that my whole string is in the form of upper case I only want to convert the extension of the image into uppercase

```
df.profile.astype(str).str.upper()
```

The results of my dataframe are

```
1                            DATA/IMAGES/PCNAYAK1971.PNG
2                         DATA/IMAGES/SC_INDIVISIBLE.JPG
3                           DATA/IMAGES/DEVPLACEMENT.JPG
4                        DATA/IMAGES/PHOENIXINFORMER.JPG
5      DATA/IMAGES/UNIA_MAY.COM/PROFILE_IMAGES/212183...
6                             DATA/IMAGES/AADANIELS3.JPG
7                        DATA/IMAGES/CHRISTI02463358.JPG
8                            DATA/IMAGES/BABIE__BEAR.JPG
9                                 DATA/IMAGES/NC0303.JPG
```

**I just only want to convert like that**

```
1                            data/images/pcnayak1971.PNG
2                         data/images/sc_indivisible.JPG
3                           data/images/devplacement.JPG
```

Comment: split('.') and then grab the first part and convert it to lowercase and append to the second part.

Comment: there will be 100k rows in the dataframe and there will be different format is there any elegant way to do that @Vishal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`str.rsplit`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) to split the strings on `'.'` from the end, and then modify and combine them using pandas' vectorized string functions:

```
l = df.profile.str.rsplit('.', n=1)
l.str[0].str.cat(l.str[-1].str.upper(), sep='.')
```

---

Lets try with the two first rows:

```
             profile
1     data/images/pcnayak1971.png
2  data/images/cs_indivisible.jpg

l = df.profile.str.rsplit('.', n=1)
df['profile'] = l.str[0].str.cat(l.str[-1].str.upper(), sep='.')

             profile
1     data/images/pcnayak1971.PNG
2  data/images/cs_indivisible.JPG
```

Comment: Beat me by 13 secs to be precise

Comment: Think it may be necessary to also specify `n=1` in the `rsplit` method to avoid any truncation..? for example, check index 5 in the OP sample data. Path contains `"UNIA_MAY.COM"`

Comment: no problem, great answer by the way, I did upvote :)